# Clarification on Vulkan multiview (stereoscopic 3D) features

Tags: 3d, vulkan

I have a few confusions about stereoscopic 3D in Vulkan.

1. What is the use of VK_KHR_multiview? Is it necessary to presenting 3D vision if I render images using only compute shaders?
2. What are the necessary extensions (device and instanes) that must be enabled to present 3D images? What do I need to query and create? And in what order?
3. What is the meaning of "multiViewport" physical device feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`VK_KHR_multiview`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/blob/master/appendices/VK_KHR_multiview.txt) is used in presenting two views from the same set of commands in a single render pass, rather than having to set up two render passes and two sets of commands. It does this via extension structs you attach to the `pNext` of, specifically [`VkRenderPassMultiviewCreateInfoKHR`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkRenderPassMultiviewCreateInfo.html), attached to [`VkRenderPassCreateInfo`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkRenderPassCreateInfo.html).

This gives a clearer explanation of what this extension provides:

> When you connect `VkRenderPassMultiviewCreateInfo` to
>   `VkRenderPassCreateInfo` - you are telling Vulkan that you want to
>   execute your pipeline TWICE ( or more - depending on the quantity of
>   view masks set in `VkRenderPassMultiviewCreateInfo`, but we are talking
>   about VR here ).
>
> There are only two differences between these two executions :
>
> - `gl_ViewIndex` variable has different value for each run ( 0, or 1 ) - you can use it as an index to the uniform to retrieve specific camera
>     matrices for each eye
> - results of the rendering go to different layer of the attachments ( layer 0, or layer 1 )

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/bjulfn/how_to_render_vk_khr_multiview_stereo_to_two/emeclt2/?context=3)

If you already accomplish this via a compute shader, `VK_KHR_multiview` isn't really going to help  unless your are using a renderpass.

From [Sascha Williems](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/multiview/multiview.cpp) example, it appears that the following extensions are required:

- obviously `VK_KHR_multiview` device extension (via `VK_KHR_MULTIVIEW_EXTENSION_NAME`)
- `VK_KHR_GET_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2_EXTENSION_NAME`, for `VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2` (instance extension).  This will enable querying of multi-view features.

In addition you'll need to modify your GLSL multi-view vertex shaders with:

```
 #extension GL_EXT_multiview : enable
```

to use `gl_ViewIndex` See [here](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/data/shaders/multiview/multiview.vert) for Sascha Willems shaders that show this, see [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/ext/GL_EXT_multiview.txt) for extension documentation.

Other than this set up, you just need to render to multiple images (as Saschas example shows).  As seen in the original reddit post there are multiple ways to accomplish this:

> Sascha's demo renders these two layers into a single swapchain image (
>   because he uses single output image )
>
> - you could render it similarly, but use two Images as output
>     attachments - create two render passes with two output attachments,
>     use texture array as input storage image ( or combined image sampler
>     if want to rescale the results )
> - you could just copy the results from texture array to your images
>     using `vkCmdCopyImage` or `vkCmdBlitImage` ( if you want to rescale the
>     results ).
> - you could create two `VkImages` that alias the same memory, that the
>     image array is using

the [multiViewport](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures.html) physical device feature defined as follows:

> `multiViewport` specifies whether more than one viewport is supported.
>   If this feature is not enabled:
>
> - The `viewportCount` and `scissorCount` members of the
>     `VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo` structure must be set to 1.
> - The `firstViewport` and `viewportCount` parameters to the `vkCmdSetViewport`
>     command must be set to 0 and 1, respectively.
> - The `firstScissor` and `scissorCount` parameters to the `vkCmdSetScissor`
>     command must be set to 0 and 1, respectively.
> - The `exclusiveScissorCount` member of the
>     `VkPipelineViewportExclusiveScissorStateCreateInfoNV` structure must be
>     set to 0 or 1.
> - The `firstExclusiveScissor` and `exclusiveScissorCount` parameters to the
>     `vkCmdSetExclusiveScissorNV` command must be set to 0 and 1,
>     respectively.

which basically just says whether or not multiple view ports are supported by the physical device.